# [Hadoop][Eclipse] Error When starting Mapreduce

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I'm working with Cygwin, Eclipse Europa 3.3.1 and Hadoop 0.19.1, When I start  a new Hadoop location on Eclipse I get this error :

Cannot connect to the Map/Reduce location: localhost
Protocol org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobSubmissionProtocol version mismatch. (client = 10, server = 16)

Any one to help me with this ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your that the correct version of your jars(Hadoop) are being referred.